# How to get access of file pointer from one function to another?

Tags: c, function, fopen, fputs

I want to store the data in location but whenever I run the code it give me message that the **fp** is undeclared. I want **fp** to be working in another function. How to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 15

int new_acc(char *name, size_t namesize);
int list_view(char *name);
int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/home/Documents/file.txt","w");      /* this is fp */

    int one='1', two='2';
    char choice[MAX], name[15] = "";
    do{
        printf("%c. Create new account\n",one);
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        fgets(choice, sizeof choice, stdin);

        if (choice[0] == one)
            {new_acc(name, sizeof name);}
    }
    while(two != choice[0]);
    return 0;}

int new_acc(char *name, size_t namesize){
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, namesize, stdin);
    fputs(name, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int new_acc(char *name, size_t namesize)
```

Change to:

```
int new_acc(FILE * fp, char *name, size_t namesize)
```

Then when you call this function in main:

```
new_acc(fp, name, sizeof name);
```

You should check the return value of `fopen`:

```
fp = fopen("/home/Documents/file.txt","w"); 
if(!fp) {
  // handle the error.
}
```

You should move `fclose(fp)` out of this function.

OT, you should change the type:

```
int one='1', two='2';
```

to `char one='1', two='2';` because you compare these variables with `char` value.

Updated for the question in comment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 15

int new_acc(FILE *fp, char *name, size_t namesize);

int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("file.txt","w");      /* this is fp */
    if(!fp) {
        printf("cannot open the file");
        return -1;
    }

    char one='1', two='2';
    char choice[MAX], name[15] = "";
    char all_accouts[100][15];
    int i = 0;
    do{
        printf("%c. Create new account\n",one);
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        fgets(choice, sizeof choice, stdin);

        if (choice[0] == one)
            {new_acc(fp, all_accouts[i], sizeof(all_accouts[i])); i++;}
    }
    while(two != choice[0]);

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("%s\n", all_accouts[j]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;

}

int new_acc(FILE *fp, char *name, size_t namesize) {
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, namesize, stdin);
    fputs(name, fp);
    return 0;
}
```

output of test:

```
1. Create new account                                                                                                     
Enter your choice: 1                                                                                                      
Enter your name: name1                                                                                                    
1. Create new account                                                                                                     
Enter your choice: 1                                                                                                      
Enter your name: name2                                                                                                    
1. Create new account                                                                                                     
Enter your choice: 2                                                                                                      
name1                                                                                                                     

name2
```

Comment: And move the `fclose(fp)` out of `new_acc`

Comment: oh, i did not see fclose in this function. I edited the answer. Thanks

Comment: Here is problem that I am facing is how to save that data, because whenever I start the previous result just finish itself from text file. I want to save that to use that another time.

Comment: you mean, you want to save the name, each time you create new account, right ? 
You can use the a 2D array: `char all_accounts[100][15]` (it means you can store maximum 100 accounts). Then use the counter, `i` for example, when you call the function`new_acc`: `new_acc(fp, all_accounts[i], sizeof all_accounts[i]);`. after creating one name you increase the counter `i++`

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the following line

   `int new_acc(char *name, size_t namesize);`

to

`int new_acc(char *name, size_t namesize, FILE *fp);`

As the file pointer will be handy - BTW - Perhaps chose a better name for the variable

2. Change

   `{new_acc(name, sizeof name);}`

to

`{new_acc(name, sizeof name, fp);}`

As this will be required

3. Change

   `int new_acc(char *name, size_t namesize){`

To

```
  int new_acc(char *name, size_t namesize, FILE *fp){
```

to match above and `fp` is required in the function

Job done!